# Read Cascading Sequence File in Spark

Tags: hadoop, serialization, apache-spark, cascading

We have some HDFS file written as cascading sequence Files which we want to process using Apache Spark. I tried using JavaPairRDD to read the key value pairs as following:

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> input = ctx.sequenceFile("file-path", String.class, String.class);
```

On running this job I get this following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find a deserializer for the Key class: 
'cascading.tuple.Tuple'. 
Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, 
if you're using custom serialization.
```

I am new to using Apache Spark. I have tried setting serialization class in spark context object but I am still getting this error. I haven't found a single example os using cascading Sequence File in Spark. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. For de serializing it one has to set the hadoop configuration. This can be done as:

```
  JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
  ctx.hadoopConfiguration().set("io.serializations","cascading.tuple.hadoop.TupleSerialization");
```

This is because hadoop takes its io.serializations from hadoop conf not from spark conf. Therefore setting this io.serializations in sparkConf is of no use. I hope it helps someone facing this this problem.